# Maven3 | Copy file hosted on one server to my code repository and then compile them

Tags: maven, maven-3, aem

Here are technology set we are using:
**Application**: Adobe AEM6
**Build**: Maven 3

**Requirement**: We have some CSS/Js/images files hosted on some 3rd party server. Requirement is

1. Pull those CSS/JS using maven, put them in our codebase style folder
2. Continue with compilation and deployment of CQ code with downloaded CSS/JS.

I need help with point 1.

Comment: We have been using Bower & Grunt as frontend technology for this usecase i have used grunt to copy files in my maven repository and then use maven in normal way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third-party [Maven download plugin](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin).

From documentation, notice an example where it downloads from an HTTP server and adds files to a project's build directory:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>install-jbpm</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>wget</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/jbpm/jBPM%203/jbpm-3.1.4/jbpm-3.1.4.zip</url>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jbpm-3.1.4</outputDirectory>
            <md5>df65b5642f33676313ebe4d5b69a3fff</md5>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: We have been using Bower & Grunt as frontend technology for this usecase i have used grunt to copy files in my maven repository and then use maven in normal way.